# Cannot reach Spring Boot component through Traefik, using Docker Swarm

Tags: spring-boot, docker-swarm, traefik

I’m trying to run a Spring Boot application consisting of 2 microservices behind a Traefik reversed proxy in Docker Swarm. When using a dual network stack for my Spring Boot webapplication, the application does not respond.

I do have the following networks

```
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
c23c6ac30ecd        bridge              bridge              local
0dcb7c122e69        docker_gwbridge     bridge              local
1e50cdf3eee7        host                host                local
wbhyv0itkveu        ingress             overlay             swarm
7sxpebq9pp7j        marc_default        overlay             swarm
e953c2393965        none                null                local
t8u63pf9l3cb        traefik-net         overlay             swarm
```

And the following configuration to start Traefik

```
docker service create \
--name traefik \
--constraint=node.role==manager \
--publish 80:80 \
--publish 8080:8080 \
--mount type=bind,source=/var/run/docker.sock,target=/var/run/docker.sock \
--network traefik-net \
traefik \
--docker \
--docker.swarmmode \
--docker.domain=traefik \
--docker.watch \
—web
```

Now, there is a docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    image: myapp-web
    env_file:
      - db-params.env
    environment:
      - server.port=8080
    deploy:
      labels:
        - 'traefik.port=8080'
    networks:
      - web
      - default

  be:
    image: myapp-be
    env_file:
      - db-params.env
    networks:
      - default

networks:
  web:
    external:
      name: traefik-net
```

And a command to start the composite:

```
docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml marc
```

In Traefik there is an URL visible: web-marc.traefik, that is defined in /etc/hosts

Unfortunately the is just a time-out when I’n asking”

```
curl http://marc-web.traefik/
```

I tried to remove the default network from the web component. It could reach the web component through Traefik, but (of course) it cannot find the be component.

Why don’t I get a reply from Spring Boot?

Answer (score 0):

It's seems to be a bug in Traefik. See https://github.com/containous/traefik/pull/2244